# How to make taller flames

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

I'm working on an animation where I need a fire to fill certain vertical area. How can I increase the height of flames in a fire simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzATaYyCf9Q). It's the source of my observations.

The first thing to know about Blender's physics simulations is that the defaults are never very useful.  So a lot of things had to change to get a realistic simulation.

For your purposes:

- The size and location of the smoke domain matters. So make sure your domain is tall enough.
- Make sure to apply scale if you've scaled it.
- These settings can make a huge difference.  Experiment to see what values you need:

  - Enable 'adaptive domain' to improve performance
  - Fire vorticity
  - Reaction speed
- The material you use for the smoke makes a huge difference.  Here's an example. The key take away from it is that the emission color has a huge impact on what the flame will look like.

[image: Fire Material]